# For every "simulation" number, I'm trying to measure when "surveillance" is greater than the "time" for each "id"

Tags: r

Firstly, apologies for my code being poor, I am relatively new to programming.

So this dataframe is showing which individual becomes infected at a particular time. It is a repetition of 4 simulations:

```
time<-rep(c(1:5),4)
sim1<-rep(c(paste("sim",1)),5)
sim2<-rep(c(paste("sim",2)),5)
sim3<-rep(c(paste("sim",3)),5)
sim4<-rep(c(paste("sim",4)),5)
sim<-c(sim1,sim2,sim3,sim4)
id<-as.vector(replicate(4,sample(1:5)))

df<-data.frame(time,sim,id)
```

So it should look like this:

```
   time   sim id
1     1 sim 1  1
2     2 sim 1  3
3     3 sim 1  2
4     4 sim 1  4
5     5 sim 1  5
6     1 sim 2  1
7     2 sim 2  5
8     3 sim 2  4
9     4 sim 2  2
10    5 sim 2  3
11    1 sim 3  2
12    2 sim 3  3
13    3 sim 3  4
14    4 sim 3  1
15    5 sim 3  5
16    1 sim 4  3
17    2 sim 4  5
18    3 sim 4  2
19    4 sim 4  1
20    5 sim 4  4
```

What I am trying to do is create a loop where I sample each simulation with a round of "surveillance". So the "surveillance" detects an infection if it's time is equal to or greater than the time of the id. However, I cannot know the id of the infected individual beforehand, hence, randomly sampling individuals. Once the game has been won by the surveillance I want to sum up all infected individuals at that point, I want to do this by using some code such as:

```
#pseudocode
sum(all(df$time<surveillance))
```

Making progress to this point would be fantastic as I would be able to determine the total "infection" within the "population".

EDIT: I have made progress with the coding:

```
surveillance<-5

df$simnu<-as.numeric(df$sim)

n<-1
simsub<-df[which(df$simnu==1),names(df)%in%c("time","sim","id")]
while (n<=surveillance){
print (n)
rndid<-df[sample(nrow(simsub),1),]
print(rndid)
if(n<rndid$time){
n<-n+1
} else {
tinf<-sum(length(df[which(simsub$time<=n),1]))
prev<-tinf/length(simsub[,1])
print(paste(prev,"prevalence"))
break
}
}
```

One major problem I have at the moment is running this surveillance for the data in each simulation, which obviously complicates things. I have a dataset at the moment in this format, and hence working out a solution using this format would be ideal.

Many thanks, I really appreciate any support, my level of r coding is beginner to intermediate, let me know what you think. My apologies if this question is formatted incorrectly or too unspecific.

Comment: Your question is not entirely clear to me. Does `df$surveillance <- df$time >= time$id` do what you want? If not, could you provide your expected output?

Comment: I'm not quite following. Thanks, let me clarify, expected output would be 'surveillance<-1:5', for each value in surveillance, measured against a random value of id and it's respective time. So, for example, if the value of surveillance is 1 and the id selected has a value of 3, then move onto surveillance value of 2, up to a maximum of 5. At 5, surveillance is guaranteed to be => the id time. If I can get to that stage with multiple simulations that would be fantastic!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain I've understood your setup. I *think* that you want to group participants according to their id number (so 4 people in each group), then for each group, count how many of them have a `time` of <= 1, a `time` of <= 2, etc, up to a `time` of <= 5.

Assuming this is correct, here is the `dplyr` way to achieve this:

```r
surveillances <-  df %>% 
                  group_by(id) %>% 
                  summarize(surv1 = sum(time <= 1), surv2 = sum(time <= 2), 
                            surv3 = sum(time <= 3), surv4 = sum(time <= 4), 
                            surv5 = sum(time <= 5))
```

So now we have a data frame with one row for each `id` and one column for each surveilance time:

```
surveillances
#> # A tibble: 5 x 6
#>      id surv1 surv2 surv3 surv4 surv5
#>   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#> 1     1     0     0     2     3     4
#> 2     2     2     2     2     3     4
#> 3     3     0     2     3     3     4
#> 4     4     2     2     2     4     4
#> 5     5     0     2     3     3     4
```

Now, presumably you want to count the proportion of infections you would pick up at each stage of surveilance. You could do this with `colSums`:

```r
colSums(as.matrix(surveillances))[-1]/nrow(df)
#> surv1 surv2 surv3 surv4 surv5 
#>   0.2   0.4   0.6   0.8   1.0
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, apologies for the lack of clarification. I've generated code which is much closer to my solution in the edit above, I am trying to group my data values by simulation and running the loop I have generated above (please see my edit to this question). All I need to do now is work out how to run the above loop for each simulation then work with the output of that. Could you help me with that?